# Using access token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I work on a c# project, which is supposed to access some WS using OAuth2.
I managed to get the code, and from the code get the access token.
Now with this token i try to access the REST WS, but when i call url, the response i get is the redirection to the login form.
My code :

```
string completeUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsUrl"] + "user/get";


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(completeUrl);
        string token = (string)Session["token"];
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Make sure service you call expect that particular way of passing auth info. There is no way to help you without knowing what the service actually expects (i.e. there could be documentation/sample somewhere).

Comment: This is not the regular way? I'm new to OAuth

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct content type?

Comment: Nope i just found that on some examples

Comment: I tried with request.Headers.Add("access_token", token);  and request.Headers.Add("token_access", token);  but nothing changed

Comment: My bad i was not calling good url. 
By the way this is working with 
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";